# Issue with New Xampp installation

Tags: php, session

I just upgraded my `Xampp` installation to **PHP 7** and when i run my site i am receiving error with my site with `session_start();`

> Warning: session_start(): open(\xampp\tmp\sess_8hsshehfq4kbf4bad892permf0, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in D:\Local server\htdocs\clients\isite\index.php on line 2

It seems php is not able to create/read session files.

I had no issue with the previous installation of **PHP5**

Also i setup `virutalHost` and some of them are working and some of them are not

> System Host file

```
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

    127.0.0.1       digitnomics
    ::1             digitnomics

    127.0.0.1       clients
    ::1             clients
```

> VirtualHost

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName clients
    ServerAlias clients
    DocumentRoot "D:\Local server\htdocs\clients"
    CustomLog logs/clients.error.logs combined
    ErrorLog logs/clients.error.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    DocumentRoot "D:\Local server\htdocs\localhost"
    CustomLog logs/localhost.error.logs combined
    ErrorLog logs/localhost.error.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName digitnomics
    ServerAlias digitnomics
    DocumentRoot "D:\Local server\htdocs\digitnomics"
    CustomLog logs/digitnomics.error.logs combined
    ErrorLog logs/digitnomics.error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

> and this line is added in httpd.conf

Include "conf/virtualhost.conf"

Receiving `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` when i try to access them.

These are the only few sites entry i mentioned here (I have more entries ) from sample here digtnomics is working the rest are not.

**UPDATE**

There is new update to Xampp for php 7 still facing same issue.

Comment: I found this in another thread. It worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/34711192/5870303

Answer (score 0):

PHP stores session info in a folder.

```
ini_set('session.save_path', 'tmp');
```

This piece of code will change the directory where it will be saving the session data to the %temp% folder. You can change it to any other folder which XAMPP will have access.

If you don't want to put this in every PHP file, you can create a php.ini in your project root and add this line:

```
session.save_path = "/path/to/your/folder"
```

Comment: I don't think you should have to set this yourself, though. XAMPP's default configuration for PHP 7 might be broken.

Comment: Nice Solution but i am not looking to modify my code. It will be pain to go through all the codes and site and update it.

Having issue with virutalHost also updated Question.

@andrea How can i fix xampp configuration?

Comment: You can also put a php.ini in your project root and add the line I'm adding into the answer