# What may cause an ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error, on xampp while using session

Tags: php, windows, apache, session, xampp

I have problem with xampp (Windows) where I have `session_start();` in my file but it like drops that request...

When I try to access page with `localhost/folder/index.php` it works but when i try
`external ip/folder/index.php` or `127.0.0.1/folder/index.php` or `[::1]/folder/index.php` it just drops connection (tried multiple browsers and chrome gives `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`... I am clueless and I desperately need help...
It worked when I removed `session_start();` from my file...
When I make new file with `session_start();` it still doesn't work...

Some error.log lines

```
[Sun Jan 10 19:33:45.805036 2016] [:error] [pid 3176:tid 1888] [client myip:50143] script 'C:/xampp/htdocs/h3x1t/i\xc2\xb4\xc2\xb4.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sun Jan 10 20:02:40.330149 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 24588:tid 552] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Jan 10 20:02:40.373728 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 24588:tid 552] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Sun Jan 10 20:04:25.949925 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 29460:tid 564] AH00428: Parent: child process 24588 exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Sun Jan 10 20:04:26.568746 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 29460:tid 564] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Jan 10 20:04:26.615700 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 29460:tid 564] AH00455: Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jan 10 20:04:26.615700 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 29460:tid 564] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Dec  9 2015 10:17:39
[Sun Jan 10 20:04:26.615700 2016] [core:notice] [pid 29460:tid 564] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Sun Jan 10 20:04:26.622190 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 29460:tid 564] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 26200
[Sun Jan 10 20:04:27.302705 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 26200:tid 560] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Jan 10 20:04:27.475560 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 26200:tid 560] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Jan 10 20:04:27.518770 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 26200:tid 560] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Sun Jan 10 20:04:28.693791 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 29460:tid 564] AH00428: Parent: child process 26200 exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Sun Jan 10 20:04:29.379751 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 29460:tid 564] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Jan 10 20:04:29.425188 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 29460:tid 564] AH00455: Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jan 10 20:04:29.425188 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 29460:tid 564] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Dec  9 2015 10:17:39
[Sun Jan 10 20:04:29.425188 2016] [core:notice] [pid 29460:tid 564] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Sun Jan 10 20:04:29.430191 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 29460:tid 564] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 30668
[Sun Jan 10 20:04:30.081357 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 30668:tid 608] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Jan 10 20:04:30.254197 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 30668:tid 608] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Jan 10 20:04:30.297173 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 30668:tid 608] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Sun Jan 10 20:06:24.444492 2016] [:error] [pid 30668:tid 1896] [client ::1:60405] script 'C:/xampp/htdocs/h3x1t/contracts.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://localhost/h3x1t/index
```

Comment: Have you checked the apache error log?What does it say..

Comment: Edit -> some error log lines.

Comment: It seems you try to access a web page as a file..C:/xampp/htdocs/h3x1t/contracts.php...

Comment: try to access as webpage http://localhost/h3x1t/contracts.php

Comment: or http://127.0.0.1/h3x1t/contracts.php

Comment: I never tried that... It doesnt work when i access it 127.0.0.1 or my external IP (ports opened).... Only through localhost... I reinstalled PHP (I had PHP 7.0.0) and it's working... I guess it's PHP 7.0.0 problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reinstalled xampp with older PHP Version...

Looks like culprit was PHP 7.0.0

EDIT: Found something probably linked to it
https://community.apachefriends.org/viewtopic.php?p=248070&sid=0b7559defe15317f41699d1ce9194e3f

EDIT2: Found this (bitnami developers)

> we have been checking the configuration of XAMPP and we found that the
>   issue is related to the use_only_cookies variable that you can find in
>   the Session's section of the php.ini file. Apache will crash if the
>   use_only_cookies variable in the Session's section is set to 0 and
>   everything is fine if it's set to 1.
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-only-cookies
>
> We also checked that the use_strict_mode should be set to 1.
>
> https://wiki.php.net/rfc/strict_sessions
>   http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-strict-mode
>
> We'll include those changes in the next version of XAMPP with PHP 7.
>   We are building the installers with the version 7.0.2 and we'll
>   release them as soon as possible.

Comment: Changed it to 0 from 1, and it actually helped me on 7.1.33 :D

Answer (score 7):

I have XAMPP with PHP7 and the same problem...

I've changed in php.ini:
session.use_only_cookies from 0 to 1 and all works.

Comment: I already linked answer to this question with enough info to fix it - but thanks!

Comment: I had same problem on windows after upgrading from xamp5.6 to 7.1 and from that point on all concurent requests started to fail.

Setting 'use_only_cookies' really helped me , tnx for tip!, althought I set it from "1" to "0" :)

Answer (score 6):

In my case, Windows Event Viewer showed more useful data. It pointed to VCRUNTIME140.dll constantly crashing Apache (which caused the console to show ERR_CONNECTION_RESET), so I updated libraries to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=52685 - then, it showed faulting module as php7ts.dll - so I've followed instructions from http://ibraransari.blogspot.com/2017/01/how-to-solve-apache-crash-fault-module.html and I was good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If things still dont work when you applied the above two answers,Clear out the cache this should solve the problem.

Comment: you mean the browser cache?