# PHP setting sessions cause error

Tags: php, session, xampp

I copy my project to my desktop. But when i run the project on desktop it does not load `login.php`.

```
session_start();
  if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
  }
```

I had the above code in my login page in order to redirect the user to index page if he is already logged in. This cause me the error.
After deleting the above piece of code `login.php` loaded successfully.

I am using xampp version compiled on 2013 on laptop and 2015 compiled version in desktop. Is this causing the error? and what is the solution for it.

Comment: do you produce any output before setting header ?

Comment: You really should *always* use `die()` after a `header('Location` to ensure PHP terminates as you expect.

Comment: page is not loading at all. it shows cant reach this web page right now

Comment: Could  you please edit your question and add complete error message?

Comment: When you have working code which stops working when you change the environment its running at it's more often than not because the new environment is using different configuration settings  than the old one and the code is relying on specific configuration settings.

Comment: @ksno  :  PHP does not provide any error messages. Webbrowser say it canot load this page

Comment: Do you have a webserver and PHP installed on that machine? and how are you accessing this as, `http://localhost/file.php` or as `file:///file.php`? You are using a `.php` extension, *right?*

Comment: @Fred  : i had xampp server installed on my meachine. and ofcourse i use .php extention.   The exact same code worked for me in my laptop

Comment: that was a "multi-part" question ;-) you answered "one".

Comment: i edited my comment above

Comment: This is the part you didn't answer to yet: *how are you accessing this as, `http://localhost/file.php` or as `file:///file.php`?* - Those are 2 different animals here.

Comment: http://localhost/file.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106727/discussion-between-abhijith-p-haridas-and-fred-ii).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36086307/4121605

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because session variable is not set first try to print that like and you should use exit() after header. It should be always used with header to stop further processing.

```
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION['username']); // just to check session exist or not
```

If it does not solve your issue then provide all your code here.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I changed my appache port number from 80 to 81 . I guess that was the error.
i made a slight change in `php.inc` file

```
session.use_only_cookies=0
```

has been changed to

```
session.use_only_cookies=1
```

Its working now

reference
[What may cause an ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error, on xampp while using session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709407/what-may-cause-an-err-connection-reset-error-on-xampp-while-using-session)